# want to change image in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I want to change an image in Codeigniter, replace the previously uploaded image and also delete previous image from folder :

Here is my Controller . But its not working:

```
public function changeImage(){

    //$user_id = $this->profile_model->changeImage();

        /************* File Upload ************/
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/user_pic/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        $filetype = $_FILES['user_pic']['type'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['user_pic']['name'];

        if($filetype == "image/jpg")
                $file_type='jpg';
            else if ($filetype == "image/gif")
                $file_type='gif';
            else if($filetype == "image/jpeg")
                $file_type='jpg';

            else if($filetype == "image/pjpeg")
                $file_type='pjpeg';
            else if($filetype ==  "image/png")
                $file_type='png';

        $_FILES['user_pic']['name']=$user_id.'.'.$file_type;

        $this->upload->do_upload('user_pic');


        $up_dtat = array('user_pic' => $_FILES['user_pic']['name']);
        $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_users',$up_dtat);
    redirect('profile');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to update the profile picture in your store file, first you need to remove the old file, fetch the old file name on the bases of user id.

Then give the file  name with this code.

```
unlink("your_path/filename.jpg"); //don't use base_url() just give the path like profile_pic/xxxxx.png
```

This code will delete the specified file from that folder.

Now i have code that i had use for the file uploads so it will also work for you try this.

```
$imgpath='uploads/profile_pic/';//path where do you want to store image
            $all_img="";
            if($_FILES["profile_pic"]['name'])//input type that you have use in file upload
            {         
               $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]);
               $image_path = $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension']; 
               $all_img.=$image_path;
               move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"],$imgpath."/".$image_path);
               $data['cm_user_profile_pic']=$all_img;//store filename in array to update in database
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the previous image only but set file name same then

**First method is :**

get old file name from table

```
$sql = "SELECT user_pic FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=?";
$get_image = $this->db->query($sql,array($user_id))->row_array();
```

set new file name as assigned to old

```
$config['file_name'] = $get_image['user_pic'];
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE; // this will overwrite your image
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

But in this case, old file and new file extension must be same
If both extensions are different then maybe image will be crashed after upload

**The second method is**

Get user_pic data from DB

And Unlink that picture

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.Your_image_folder.$get_image['user_pic']);
```

And check file is upload or not

```
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('user_pic')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
         }

         else { 
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
         }
```

Comment: not working ... please check my editing function in last comment @Nidhi

Comment: explain me issue @Sabbir... Not working but in which case? An image is not overridden or not delete??